# How to get the matching keys in my Generic getList method (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, key-value

For certain reasons, I need a method that returns a list without first specifying an entity or using a repository.

If you look at my output you can see that only the values are returned. However, my goal is to include the keys. Does anyone have any idea how I should rebuild my methods to output the keys as well?

My RestController

```
 @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> getList(String tableName, String schemaName) {
        final List<Object> empObject = configService.getList(tableName, schemaName);

        return ResponseEntityBuilderUtils.ok(empObject);

    }
```

My Service

```
@Override
    public List<Object> getList(String tableName, String schemaName) {
        final String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + tableName;
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);

        final List<Object> empObject = query.getResultList();

        return empObject;
    }
```

My Output

```
[
    [
        1,
        1,
        "shape",
        null,
        null,
        "0212411",
        0,
        "kugel"
    ],
    [
        2,
        1,
        "shape",
        null,
        null,
        "02012111",
        0,
        "rechteck"
    ],
    [
        3,
        1,
        "shape",
        null,
        null,
        "02012111",
        0,
        "prism"
    ]
]
```

How it should be:

```
[
    [
        id: 1,
        analytic_id: 1,
        propertytype: "shape",
        min_val: null,
        max_val: null,
        string_val: "0212411",
        case_else: 0,
        result: "kugel"
    ],
    [
        id: 2,
        analytic_id: 1,
        propertytype: "shape",
        min_val: null,
        max_val: null,
        string_val: "02012111",
        case_else: 0,
        result: "rechtecht"
    ],
    [
        id: 3,
        analytic_id: 1,
        propertytype: "shape",
        min_val: null,
        max_val: null,
        string_val: "02012111",
        case_else: 0,
        result: "rechtecht"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to achieve this:

1. Use a RowMapper to create appropriate Java objects. See [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html).
2. Use a custom JSON-Mapper to convert the Java-Objects into JSON-Objects. See [Custom serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846232/11934850).